# How can I add Multiple Product IDs in a PHP Action

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Good Day, I need to add multiple product ids to an action. I'm trying to allow vendors to not sell some of their products and be contacted before anyone makes a purchase the code below is what I have used for a single product and would like to know how I can add more product ids.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
        return ($product->id == 24 ? false : $is_purchasable);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: return in_array($product->id, array(24,25,26,27)) ? false : $is_purchasable;

Comment: Doesn't work but thanks.

Comment: @MohammadYousefi...Apologies it does work...there was an oversight on my end. THANKS so much!

Comment: I,m happy helped you @Qubo

Answer (score 0):

```
$purchaseable_product_ids = array(20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
return ( !in_array( $product->id, $purchaseable_product_ids ) ? false : $is_purchasable)
```